# Unable to add Phonegap/Cordova Push notification plugin using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, git, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I am trying to install [Phonegap Push Notification Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) via Visual Studio 2015 Plugin installation. I am able to add push notification plugin successfully in project.
[image]

But when i build the solution i am getting error as shown below.
[image]
Below is the Output log

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: work, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Buildfile: c:\Users\deep.mehta\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects1\work\work\platforms\android\build.xml
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Application
1>
1>  -pre-clean:
1>
1>  clean:
1>  [getlibpath] Library dependencies:
1>  [getlibpath]
1>  [getlibpath] ------------------
1>  [getlibpath] Ordered libraries:
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>
1>  nodeps:
1>
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
1>
1>  -pre-clean:
1>
1>  clean:
1>
1>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>  Total time: 0 seconds
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>
1>  c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work>"C:\Users\deep.mehta\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd"   build --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName work --npmInstallDir C:\Users\deep.mehta\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US --buildTarget AndroidDevice
1>  ------ Cordova tools 4.3.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: work
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\deep.mehta\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidDevice
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: org.apache.cordova.device@0.3.0
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: org.apache.cordova.device@0.3.0,com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin@2.5.0
1>  ------ Adding plugin: com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin@2.5.0
1>  Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin@2.5.0"
1>  Fetching plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin@2.5.0" via plugin registry
1>MDAVSCLI : npm error : 404 Not Found: com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried other work around adding plugin manually i.e locally but getting same error. Created New project and tried to install push notification plugin but getting same results. If i remove push notification and build the solution it works.
Version of visual studio i am using is 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can install it with the command-line (first change the directory):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

if those don't work:

```
cd C:\SomePath
git clone https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
cordova plugin add C:\SomePath\PushPlugin
```

if using PhoneGap, the commands are rather:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
phonegap local plugin add C:\SomePath\PushPlugin
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for helping me out. I tried doing your way. was able to install the plugin but still visual studio was not able to identify my plugin.

Comment: yes that's correct. After new update in visual studio they have changed few things in config.xml the way we declare plugins. after fixing that i was able to run the code.